# Switching between two idle animation states

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have one idle state for my player character that's default.

However, I want a secondary idle. When I press the C key, it goes to that second idle animation and stays there. When I press the X key, it goes back to the default idle animation.

But this is where the problem starts. When I press the C key to switch to the secondary animation again, is quickly jumps to the second idle animation and back to the default animation without staying or awaiting any further commands.

I want it to stay where I tell it to.

Additionally, after the problems happens and I hit the C key again, the animation doesn't change. But when I hit the X key instead at this point, and then the C key after this, once again it goes back and forth between animations.

So I believe that it 'thinks' it's been switched when it really hasn't. If you could tell me what to do to fix this issue I'll be your best friend. Thanks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

private Animator anim;
Rigidbody2D rb;
public float Speed;
private bool aim = false;
private bool shot = false;
private bool idle = true;
public Transform arrowSpawn;
public GameObject arrowPrefab;
private bool idle2 = false;


void Start()
{

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Movement();
    Inputer();
    Morph (); 

}

void Movement()
{
    float moveH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (moveH * Speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (moveH));


}

void Inputer()
{

    if (!aim && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S)) {

        aim = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("AIm");
    }

    if (aim && Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.S)) {
        shot = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("Shot");

    }

    if (shot) {
        shot = false;
        aim = false;
        idle = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("Idle");
        Instantiate (arrowPrefab, arrowSpawn.position, arrowSpawn.rotation);

    }
}

    void Morph()
{
    idle = !idle2;

    if (idle && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {
        idle2 = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("idle2");
    }

    if (!idle && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.X)) {

        idle = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("Idle");
        idle2 = false;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure - when I trace through the logic, it seems to all work, but... well, the handling on idle and idle2 seems a bit suspect.

I mean, look at the logic on the 'X' key:

1. Turn idle on
2. Kick off the idle trigger
3. Turn idle2 off

... and on the 'C' key:

1. Turn idle2 on
2. Kick off the idle2 trigger

... where's the idle off?  It's seeming to wait around for the next Morph() function to set that variable.  Worse, if idle2 gets set to false anywhere else in the code, your Morph() function will flip idle to true... but without kicking off your Idle trigger.

I'd suggest trying one of these out to see if they work for you:

```
void Morph()
{
    if (!idle && !idle2)
        anim.SetTrigger ("Idle");
    idle = !idle2;

    if (idle && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {
        idle2 = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("idle2");
    }

    if (!idle && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.X)) {
        idle = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("Idle");
        idle2 = false;
    }
}
```

... or ...

```
void Morph()
{
    if (idle && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {
        idle2 = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("idle2");
        idle = false;
        return;
    }
    if (!idle && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.X)) {
        idle = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("Idle");
        idle2 = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just tried them. The results are exactly the same. I know that the problem somewhere is with the idle's of course and you did clean up my code a little. I didn't think about putting in the returns, so thanks for that. But the problem remains with both versions.

Comment: OH! just figured it out best buddy! i made a secondary trigger in the animator called idle1. Then i linked it up from the second idle to the first using idle1, and replaced it with anim.SetTrigger command with anim.SetTrigger ("Idle1"); Thanks for the assist!